# Did I use an inverse matrix correctly to solve for the standard matrix of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I am trying to find the standard matrix $A$ of a linear transformation $T$, where
$$
T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3
$$
and
$$
T(u_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},
T(u_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
T(u_3) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
for the vectors $    u_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix},
    u_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix},
    u_3 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

What I first did was write all the transformations as a single equation, with $M$ representing the standard matrix of $T$:
$$
        M\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & -1 \\
        2 & 1 & 2 \\
        -1 & 2 & 1 \\
      \end{bmatrix}
      =
      \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
      \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$
Then, I let the "input" matrix be $A$, that is
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & -1 \\
    2 & 1 & 2 \\
    -1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and I solved for its inverse $A^{-1}$.

Then, I multiplied $A^{-1}$ across (1):
$$
        MAA^{-1}
      =
      \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
      \end{bmatrix}A^{-1} $$

As $AA^{-1} = I$, it is eliminated from the equation, and hence
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
      \end{bmatrix}A^{-1}$$

That is, the product of $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
      \end{bmatrix}$ and $A^{-1}$ is the standard matrix $M$ of the linear transformation $T$.

Would anyone be so kind to let me know if they spot any error or if I there are any knowledge gaps in my working?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes that's how you will get matrix with respect to standard basis which I suppose is called standard matrix of the representation

Comment: Thanks Tony Pizza! I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes.. it's correct